# Use Context API and functional component as service in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a context API:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ userInfo, setUserInfo }}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
};

export { UserContextProvider, UserContext };
```

and use it in App.js:

```
<UserContextProvider>
  // Router,...
</UserContextProvider>
```

Well, I gonna use context API in component like a service:

```
import { UserContext } from "...";

function UserService() {
    const { userInfo, setUserInfo } = useContext(UserContext);


    const updateUserInfo = (newUserInfo) => {
         setUserInfo(newUserInfo); // for example: {name:'x'}
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now I wanna use `UserService` inside a component without add `<UserService />` ? How can I call `UserService.updateUserInfo()`?

Comment: Why not a custom hook?

Comment: Make it a custom hook and return the function you want to expose?

Comment: I tried it, but I have a problem. I use `Provider` and `Consumer` of context  in `App.js` and `useContext(UserContext)` inside of my custom hook will be undefined. because `App` not init yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your don't need to `userService`.You can use `UserContext` directly inside `App.js` and access to its function but you must wrap `App.js` inside `UserContextProvider` like:

```
<UserContextProvider>
   <App />
</UserContextProvider>
```

Or you can use `HOC(higher order component)` like:

```
const withUsersContext = (Comp) => {
    return (props) => (
        <UserContextProvider>
            <Comp {...props} />
        </UserContextProvider>
    );
};

// then inside App.js:
...
export default withUsersContext(App)
```

Now inside `App.js`:

```
const { userInfo, setUserInfo } = useContext(UserContext);
```

Note: if you wanna use `UserContext` inside something like `UserService` you must write a custom hook for `UserService`([rules of react-hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)).

Custom hooks for `UserService`:

```
function useUserService() {
    const { userInfo, setUserInfo } = useContext(UserContext);

    const updateUserInfo = (newUserInfo) => {
         setUserInfo(newUserInfo);
    }

    return { updateUserInfo };
}
```

How to use inside a component:

```
...
const { updateUserInfo }= useUserService();
...
```